# Data object with different language options. Javascript implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this weird case when I have to manage a few small texts depending on page language using javascript. Just imagine you need to replace some parts of the template depending on html lang attribute. So I created multidimensional data object and decided to go with the following way around it. Everything works fine but I feel like it is not the best practice and maybe I could avoid using switch:

**jsbin version:** http://jsbin.com/EvEciVa/2/

```
$(function(){

var lang = $('html').attr('lang'),
    text;

var obj = {
  'en' : {
    'title' : 'Title english',
    'url' : 'en.html'   
  },
  'fr' : {
    'title' : 'Title french',
    'url' : 'fr.html',   
  }               
};

switch(lang){               
  case'fr':
  text = [obj.fr.title,obj.fr.url];
  break;               
  default:
  text = [obj.en.title,obj.en.url];
}

  $('body').prepend('<a href="'+text[1]+'">'+text[0]+'</a>');

});
```

The question is: As far as I have the lang attribute value (the language), maybe I could avoid using switch and duplicate cases, instead I could implement the lang value as variable to access data object, something like this `[obj.lang.title,obj.lang.url];` Of course it wont work in my case.

I would appreciate any opinion. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid having the `switch` statement, you can set a default value like this:

```
var lang = $('html').attr('lang') || 'en';
```

This means that `en` is the default, to be overridden if there is a `lang` set. You can then use bracket notation to access the object like this:

```
$('body').prepend('<a href="' + obj[lang].url + '">' + obj[lang].title + '</a>');
```

Comment: Thank you Rory, although I cant get it work with default en. For example if I change lang="fr" to lang that does not exist like lang="dfgdfg" It wont take en text. Just undefined.

Comment: @devjs11 that's odd. Try using `var lang = $('html').prop('lang') || 'en';` instead.

Comment: Ok, it works only if lang attribute is omitted but it wont work if the value of lang tag does not exist in data object. Can this be solved? thank you.

Comment: Fixed it with the following code instead if(obj[lang] === undefined){lang = 'en';}

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need an array in this case:

```
$('body').prepend('<a href="'+obj[lang].url+'">'+obj[lang].title+'</a>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use bracket notation

```
text = [obj[lang].title,obj[lang].url];
```

I would drop the array, and just put the title/url in the string.

```
var data = obj[lang];
$('body').prepend('<a href="' + data.url + '">' + data.text + '</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assign the localized object to another variable and work from there. This way, all the localization code can reference the same object without having to deal with handling the language logic and at a later date you can switch to external localization files, should you need to.

```
$(function(){

  var lang = $('html').attr('lang') || 'en',
        text;


  var obj = {
    'en' : {
      'title' : 'Title english',
      'url' : 'en.html'   
    },
    'fr' : {
      'title' : 'Title french',
      'url' : 'fr.html',   
    }               
  };


  var translations = obj[lang];


  $('body').prepend('<a href="'+translations.url+'">'+translations.text+'</a>');

});
```

And also, as Rory mentioned, setting a default value is a very good idea.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid the `switch` statement you can just check whether the attributed language is apparent in your object, and else choose english:

```
var lang = $('html').attr('lang');
if (! (lang in obj))
    lang = "en";

// then:
'<a href="' + obj[lang].url + '">' + obj[lang].title + '</a>'
```

Or, maybe easier, use the shorter

```
var localisation = obj[ $('html').attr('lang') ] || obj.en;

'<a href="' + localisation.url + '">' + localisation.title + '</a>'
```